# ASP.NET WebForm ListBox data not retained between postbacks

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 list boxes on a WebForm page. I populate the first during page_load, and use Javascript to transfer items from the first to the second, using a button on the client side. I also have a "Save" button on the page, for persisting the data.

I transfer a few items from the first list box to the second and then click the "Save" button (which causes a postback). But when I inspected Items.Count of the second list box, it shows 0 at every break point.

Any idea on how to retain the data on the second list box?

Comment: Put html and code in support of your code. Only than some one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

your javascript code does not change the controls server side becaus the changes are only clientside.
try makeing it all serverside
you can call the fuction either whhen a button is

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
{
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
    foreach (var item in sourceItems)
    {
        destination.Items.Add(item);
    }
    while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}

private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListBoxItems(FirstListbox, LastListbox);
}
```